# Get ExceptionInInitializerError with singleton class in unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, initialization, singleton

I have a singleton class like this

```
public class EventProcessor{
     //........

   private EventProcessor() {
     Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
     String scheme = requiredHttps() ? "https" : "http";
     m_webTarget = client.target(..........);
   }

   public static EventProcessor getAuditEventProcessor() {
        return m_EventProcessor.instance();
 }

   protected boolean requiredHttps() {
       // read value from config file
       // Configuration class is also a singleton and getConfig() is a static method
        Map map = Configuration.getConfig().getCurrent().getSecuritySettings().getSettings();  


      //...............
   }
}
```

when I write the unit test, I have a setup method like this

```
private EventProcessor m_EventProcessor;

 @Before
 public void setup() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  m_EventProcessor = EventProcessor.getAuditEventProcessor();      
 }
```

I got ExceptionInInitializerError for "m_EventProcessor = EventProcessor.getAuditEventProcessor();" Can someone help me to figure out what's the peoblem for that? Is it because call a singleton class in another singleton class?

Comment: what is m_EventProcessor.instance() supposed to be?

Comment: Just a singleton instance

Comment: What is the exception that is wrapped in the `ExceptionInInitializerError`?

Comment: besides the fact that it makes no sense, I'm surprised it compiles

Comment: Got NullPointer exception for all the test cases. Just cannot initialize the class. It worked well before I added that requiredHttps() method.

Comment: why do you have 2 different fonts of quotation marks lol